# foreign keys in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I having trouble creating a foreign key in sql 2005.

my primary key table has a primary key that spans 2 columns.

I want to create my foreign key so it references a column in my primary table but I want to specify a static value for the second column - is this possible?

Comment: can you show us the table structures for the two tables, and how you tried to create the foreign key??

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this - if you reference a parent table from a child table, you have to reference all columns of the primary key on the parent table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ChildTable_ParentTable
  FOREIGN KEY (col1, col2) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(pkCol1, pkCol2)
```

You cannot suddenly introduce for "static" value into your reference.

What you could do on the child table would be to put a CHECK CONSTRAINT on that second column to make it a "static" value - but then you can never have any other value in that column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_col2_Static CHECK (col2 = 4)
```

Is that what you are looking for??

Comment: thanks for you answer. I'm happy to reference all columns of the primary key - just that I want to specify a static value for the 2nd column.

e.g primary table goods
id  type  name
1    fruit  apple
2    fruit  orange
3    veg    carrot    ...

I may want a foreign key on a column that enforces fruit types only. so the foreign key will reference the id column but also the secondary primary key column of type should constrained to fruit.

this must be a common problem when using a 'generic' table with a 'type' descriminator column to store different things

Comment: @Bal: maybe - but that's a rather bad design, in my opinion. I don't know of any way to specify that as a foreign key constraint.

Comment: The only real option I see is in SQL Server **2008** only - have a unique, filtered index on the one column on your main table where the second column is = 1 - then you could reference that filtered unique index from your child table. It's a bit of a hack, but it probably would work.